# Axiom of Choice and Number Theory

Tags: set-theory, nt.number-theory

There are so many applications of the Axiom of Choice (and consequently its equivalents) in number theory. But do you know any application of the Zorn's Lemma in Number Theory !?  I mean a theorem or a problem in this field that uses Zorn's Lemma ?

**Edit:** of course any application of AC is equivalent to an application of the Zorn's Lemma. But I am sure you agree that some proofs work better with AC, some work better with the Well ordering axiom and some work better with Zorn's Lemma. When we prove that  **any vector space has a base** we use Zorn's lemma. Nobody writes a proof with well ordering axiom while **anybody can write such a proof**.

Comment: Why do people vote up questions like this?

Comment: Jekteem, please give us an example of an application of the Axiom of Choice in number theory, and explain why it is not equivalently an application of Zorn's lemma.

Comment: The last sentence is quite a stretch. In my experience, a disturbing number of people write proofs using well ordering and transfinite induction, despite that there is a shorter proof using Zorn’s lemma.

Comment: @Emil: Interesting.  My experience has been exactly the opposite...

Comment: Hindman's theorem has a proof using Zorn's lemma. See, e.e., here: http://www.math.toronto.edu/lgoldmak/Hindman.pdf

Comment: And I suppose existence of maximal ideals does not count as "number theory"?

Comment: Concerning the last sentence of the question and Emil's comment: I sometimes find it helpful to use transfinite induction instead of Zorn's Lemma because it makes it easier to think (and write) about interleaving the construction with new sorts of steps, in order to obtain some additional properties of the object being constructed.

Comment: Transfinite induction works in ZF.

Comment: Btw, I don't use Zorn's lemma to prove that every vector space has a basis.  I use the Teichmüller-Tukey lemma, which saves one step in the proof. (You don't have to argue that the increasing union of a family of linear independent sets is linearly independent.) 

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Is there any relation between AC and Euclidlean Geometry ??

Comment: @Dimros: I have no idea. You can ask it as a new question.

Answer (score 9):

There is a metatheorem that the Axiom of Choice is not necessary to prove any statements of Arithmetic, any proof of a statement about integers that uses AC can be constructively transformed into a proof which does not use that axiom. This comes under the heading of Shoenfield Absoluteness; see this [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absoluteness#Shoenfield.27s_absoluteness_theorem), and also this [MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/71965/a-limit-to-shoenfield-absoluteness).

Comment: A precise statement or reference would be nice here. 

Comment: Really? Even for statements like Fermat last theorem?

Comment: Todd: Shoenfield Absoluteness. See, e.g., this MO question which contains a short summary of the result: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/71965/a-limit-to-shoenfield-absoluteness

Comment: Also, Wikipedia has a nice short summary: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absoluteness#Shoenfield.27s_absoluteness_theorem

Comment: However, number theory is usually understood to encompass much more than arithmetic: [MSC](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/msc/msc2010.html?t=11-XX&s=&btn=Search&ls=s)  Tools from real and complex analysis are often used, which suggests that countable choice or DC may play a role. On the other hand, proofs from number theory often have a very "effective" taste. 

Comment: Thanks, Grant. I'm going to edit that remark into the answer, under the assumption this is what Joe Shipman had in mind. If it's not, then he can re-edit to indicate what he did have in mind. 

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Is there any relation between AC and Euclidlean Geometry ??

Comment: @Dimros: I have no idea. You can ask it as a new question.