# AC and Euclidean Geometry

Tags: set-theory, geometry

**It there any relation between the axiom of choice and Euclidean Geometry ??**

I mean what are the known statements, theorems or results in euclidean geometry that are dependent on AC ?? (this question has been asked by someone else as a comment to my last question. See [HERE](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/118959/axiom-of-choice-and-number-theory))

Comment: Both things are called "axioms"...

Comment: @Asaf: As a set theorist you mean no relation exists. No statement or theorem or result in euclidean geometry is dependent on AC ? Is it provable ??

Comment: I never said anything about that. It also depends on what you define as Euclidean geometry. One could argue that the Banach-Tarski theorem applies to Euclidean geometry; while another could argue that the classical Euclidean geometry is effectively a constructive theory and there is no appeal to infinitary arguments which would require the axiom of choice. I only said that both the axioms of Euclidean geometry and the axiom of choice are named "axioms".

Comment: @Asaf: I see :) 

Comment: @Asaf: But your comment about Banach-Tarski is interesting. What is your own opinion ? 

Comment: What do you mean by a relation? As it stands, this is not a real question.

Comment: @Emil: I have edited the question. 

Comment: @Jekteem Since these are your questions, what do you mean by Set Theory and Euclidean Geometry? What do you see as results which require an actual infinity? Consider the claims: 1. There is a set of circles in Euclidean 3-space which use each point exactly once.  2.Color the integers red/blue then there is an infinite set $S$ so that all the differences  $|i-j|$  for  $i,j \in S$  have the same color. Is the first Euclidean Geometry? Is the second Number Theory? 

Answer (score 7):

Tarski gave a first-order formulation of Euclidean geometry and proved it complete (without using the axiom of choice).  In particular, that means that Euclidean geometry is the same in every model of ZF, with or without choice.  One might question whether Tarski's formulation actually captures all of Euclidean geometry, but it certainly includes everything in Euclid.